# Replicating Ant 'targets' in Maven

Tags: maven, ant, maven-profiles, maven-ant-tasks

I know this question has been asked, but all the responses I have read have not given me the advice I need, so apologies if this answer is out there buried somewhere and I haven't found it.

I am deploying our system using Maven, and a full deployment would take several steps, in order. If a change is made to a middle step, only that step and it's dependent steps needs to be redeployed. The steps are time consuming, and so deploying everything from scratch (currently ~35 minutes) is very painful. (For those interested, there is remote database deployment, followed by the creation and deployment of 2 base docker images and several docker image/containers.)

The deployment steps are basically "copy these files to remote server by scp, then run this command via sshexec". As such, it is currently a long single ant task with these steps.

If I were using Ant proper, I'd be able to specify targets and do it that way. I'm not unfamiliar with Maven, but I don't know the proper idiomatic way of dealing with this sort of process. I've seen someone suggest using profiles and this seems the most suitable solution, however there is one step I haven't been able to duplicate.

Say I have 5 steps, step 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. 5 depends on 4, 4 on 3, etc. I can have a profile step for each, and run `mvn -P 1,2,3,4,5` to get what I need. If I only make a change to 3, then I could run `mvn -P 3,4,5`, my problem is however that there are many more steps, not so obviously numbered and it is a moving target at the moment for the other developers as we build our product.

Is there a way, using profiles or otherwise, for me and my developers to basically say `mvn -P stepX` and the profile set up in step "x" to say "run profile X, then Y, then Z" ?

Many thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: This sounds like a misuse of Maven, cause Maven is build tool but not a deployment tool. Here you might be at the point either creating a maven plugin which handles such things in your way or use an Ant script (which might be called by maven-antrun-plugin) or use things like puppet, chef, docker ?

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise, I realise it isn't built as a deployment tool, but we have to use it as such nonetheless. As mentioned in the question, this is actually to build and deploy docker containers.